# What is the meaning of « à vue de nez » in this specific context?

Tags: expressions

> Où vous allez ? À l'auberge la plus proche, à vue de nez.

I’m torn between two interpretations:

1. Where are you going? To the nearest inn, **I guess**.

   / Suggesting that this is **just a wild guess**. /
2. Where are you going? To the nearest inn, **approximately**?

   / Practically, it is hard to say for sure which inn is the nearest, but indicating the one **apparently** nearest, **roughly speaking**. /

Comment: You understand what à *vue de nez* means but more context is needed to understand how to interpret it here.

Comment: Hi. Three people are casually discussing what they are going to do from now on, and one of them says this phrase. My hunch is leaning towards the first interpretation, since it is not as if they were trying to determine which inn is the nearest. Can the phrase "à vue de nez" be used as a sort of afterthought to mean "... , je parie."?

Comment: I think you will have to provide the precise text before and after the sentance you want to translate for us to be aware of context.

Comment: Person A said: « Je ferais mieux d'y aller. Bonne continuation. » And then Person B said the very sentence in this post.

Comment: This example is weird to start with, where does it come from ? I always have seens "à vue de nez" used in an answer to a question asked **to** you and not **by** you to which you don't know the precise answer and are trying a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consodering the two sentences:

> - Je ferais mieux d'y aller. Bonne continuation.
> - Où vous allez ? À l'auberge la plus proche, à vue de nez.

Your first assertion:

> Where are you going? To the nearest inn, I guess.

is the right one.

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to swap "à vue de nez" with "je parie" at the end of a sentence?

Comment: @LUNA: yes, it is.

Comment: « À vue de nez, il te reste environ 15 heures. » In this sentence, does "à vue de nez" mean "environ / approximately" rather than "je parie / I guess"? Thanks.

Comment: @LUNA: I would say, in this case, "roughly"